# List of estuary/mouth size for European rivers

Tags: rivers, estuary

I am looking for a list that contains either the size of estuaries or river mouths of European rivers. Is there such a list available somewhere? I have been looking for a while but only found lists covering the river length or the amount of discharge.

Comment: What do you mean by 'size', is it the area the estuaries cover or their discharge or their crossectional length?

Comment: the area the estaurie covers or the crossectional length.  Either one would be fine.